# Latin squares with one cycle type?

Tags: permutations, combinatorial-designs, latin-square

Now [cross-posted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415514/latin-squares-with-one-cycle-type) because of no answers here.

The following Latin square

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
2&1&4&5&6&7&8&3\\
3&4&1&6&2&8&5&7\\
4&3&2&8&7&1&6&5\\
5&6&7&1&8&4&3&2\\
6&5&8&7&3&2&4&1\\
7&8&5&2&4&3&1&6\\
8&7&6&3&1&5&2&4
\end{bmatrix}$$

has the property that for all pairs of two different rows $a$ and $b$, the permutations $ab^{-1}$ have the same cycle type (one 2-cycle and one 6-cycle).

What is known about such Latin squares? (With the property that all $ab^{-1}$ have the same cycle type, not necessarily the (2, 6) cycle type from the example above.) For example, do they have a particular structure, for which cycle types do they exist, do they have a name, etc?